# Selenium doesn't recognise xpath

Tags: java, select, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to get from a drop down list values. Unfortunately I can't get it, because my code can't recognise the xpath.

Here's my code:

```
  WebElement selector = driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('search')/x:fieldset/x:table[1]/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[1]/x:select"));
  Select s = new Select(selector);
  List<WebElement> options = s.getOptions();
  for (WebElement wb : options) {
     System.out.println(wb.getText());
  }
```

The problem is with the 1st line (WebElement selector). In output I get something like this:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression
>   'id('search')/x:fieldset/x:table[1]/x:tbody/x:tr[2]/x:td[1]/x:select'
>   cannot be evaluated

I've even tried to find by name or class, but selenium still doesn't find this list.

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That isn't a valid XPath selector.

Comment: Your xpath expression is wrong and can not not be parsed. Read a bit about xpath http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ganjira, This is no way to write a xpath. If you find it tough to recognize item . Use Selenium IDE 'Select' button.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide sample of html page on which you try to find your element, it would be very helpful. Anyway, try to search using css selectors e.g.

```
WebElement selector = driver.findElement(By.css("#search > select"));
```